# Where does 'Superman Unchained' fit in the current New 52 timeline?

Tags: dc, superman

DC Comics is publishing another title of Superman, called "Superman Unchained". How does this title fit in the current New 52 timeline?

Comment: I've read both issues released so far, and no explicit time frame was given. I assumed it was placed in the present day.

Comment: So concurrently to "Superman" and "Justice League"? Huh, interesting! I wonder how different it will be from "Superman" then.

Comment: I think it's just different stories that run concurrently to the other books, like how Batman has Detective Comics, Dark Knight, Batman, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Superman Unchained, written by Scott Snyder and drawn by Jim Lee is the modern day, New 52 Superman.**

- It references all the recent changes, and shows all of the characters in their New 52 guises. Bruce Wayne, Cyborg, and Wonder Woman as well as mentions of the Justice League, all appear, but part of the current story arc is reminiscent of some Post-Crisis era stories.

> Particularly, the revival of General Lane (who died heroically, Post-Crisis) and his technology for combatting Superman.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a placement in a chronological timeline, [Fans have placed it](http://www.comicvine.com/dc-comics/4010-10/forums/dc-new-52-reading-order-new-reader-698621/) before Catwoman 17 but after Justice League Dark 21. In Superman Only Timeline it'd be before Superman 23.3 but after Superman 20.